# KMM - Casting Sealed Classes in Swift

Tags: swift, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm fairly new to KMM/Swift and am struggling to cast sealed classes.

I have the following class:

```
data class DataPointState(val id: Long? = null){
 sealed class MultiSelectOptions<T> {
        data class Strings(val options: List<UserGeneratedString>) :
            MultiSelectOptions<List<UserGeneratedString>>()
        data class Lifts(val options: List<Lift>) : MultiSelectOptions<List<Lift>>()

       
    }
 data class EditState(
        val value: InputData? = null
    ) {
        sealed class InputData { 
             data class MultiSelectOptions(val list: DataPointState.MultiSelectOptions<*>) :
                InputData()
             //More data classes here
    }
}
```

On the Android side, I can type check/cast my Input data to MultiSelectOptions, and then type check/cast to Lifts or Strings:

```
 when (value) {     
   ...          
    is DataPointState.EditState.InputData.MultiSelectOptions -> FlowRow(
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(4.dp)
        ) {
            value.list.let {
                when (it) {
                    is DataPointState.MultiSelectOptions.Lifts -> it.options.forEach {
                        ...
                    }

                    is DataPointState.MultiSelectOptions.Strings -> it.options.forEach {
                        ...
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

But when I try to do the equivalent in Swift I get a warning `Cast from 'DataPointStateMultiSelectOptions<AnyObject>' to unrelated type 'DataPointStateMultiSelectOptionsLifts' always fails`

```
  switch value {  
          case let value as DataPointState.EditStateInputDataMultiSelectOptions:
           
                switch value.list {
                case let list as DataPointStateMultiSelectOptionsLifts :
                    Text("test")
                default:
                    EmptyView()
                }
                
            }
```

Any help figuring this out is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift doesn't have an equivalent of the star project you used in `MultiSelectOptions<*>`.

It turns out `MultiSelectOptions<*>` got translated to `MultiSelectOptions<AnyObject>`, kind of similar to `MultiSelectOptions<Any>` in Kotlin. As you may know, `MultiSelectOptions<Any>` is unrelated to `MultiSelectOptions.Lifts`, so that's why you got the warning.

As far as I know, Kotlin interops with Swift by turning its generics to Objective-C's lightweight generics first. At this point, `MultiSelectOptions<*>` is turned into `MultiSelectOptions<id>`. And finally it gets imported into Swift as `MultiSelectOptions<AnyObject>`.

Objective-C's lightweight generics are also "erased" similar to how Kotlin's are. There is no runtime mechanism to enforce that `MultiSelectOptions<AnyObject>` can't be a `MultiSelectOptions<[Lift]>`.

If you cast to `AnyObject` first, and then cast to `Lift`, you can bypass Swift's strict enforcement of generic types.

```
switch value.list as AnyObject {
case let list as DataPointStateMultiSelectOptionsLifts:
    Text("test")
default:
    EmptyView()
}
```

Comment: Something so simple as a cast to AnyObject! Thank you for the help and the detailed explanation